# How can I have more flexible serialization and deserialization in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

If I serialize an object in Java, and then later add an extra field to the java class, I can't deserialize the object into the modified class.

Is there a serialization library or some way that I can have deserialization be less strict, like if there is an extra field added to the class then it just fills that with null upon deserialization of the old version of the class?

Comment: you don't need java's serialization. check out some simple xml/json seralization libs.

Comment: Serialized Java Object have the huge disadvantage to not be readable unless you de-serialize them again. Using a text-based format such as xml or json makes the content readable as well as it makes the serialization way more customizable (i.e. your version problem)

Answer (score 7):

You need to keep a `serialVersionUID` on your class. Check out the section "Version Control" in [this article by Sun](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Comment: Updated link of article by Sun http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html

Answer (score 5):

You've got lots of potential options.

You could use a graph serialisation library to define and manage your format e.g. Google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) or [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/). I believe both of these have built-in support for versioning.

You can write your own custom serialisation code and handle the versions explicitly - e.g. serializing to a flexible format like XML. When reading the XML you can configure it to use default values if a particular field isn't specified.

Or you could design your class in a "flexible" way, e.g. have all the fields stored in a HashMap and indexed by Strings. Depending on what you are trying to do, this may be a convenient option.

Comment: I think that JSON would be an even better format for serialization than XML, at the cost of needing a JSON library.

Comment: @W.Craig - yes I agree, JSON is a great choice as well.

Comment: @W.Craig - You would have that cost for a xml lib as well - I wouldn't advise anyone to parse xml by himself. If Xml: Use JAXB. Less overhead: JSON.

Comment: @f1sh, with Java, you'll already have the XML libraries as part of the runtime; you'd need to add the JSON library (admittedly its much smaller/faster than the XML equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair few serialization libraries, take a look at Simple though:

http://simple.sourceforge.net/

or as mentioned above Google Protocol Buffers.

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/

Answer (score 0):

Implement [Externalizable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) and you can do whatever you want. The puts the onus of serial/deserialization completely upon the class being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a serialVersionUID? This must be present (and unchanged) if you want to serialize / deserialize different Versions of a class.

Furthermore you can add the following two methods to your class to define exactly the serialization process:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
 throws IOException;
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
 throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

The Javadoc of ObjectInputStream gives more detail on its usage.

Answer (score 0):

> If I serialize an object in Java, and
>   then later add an extra field to the
>   java class, I can't deserialize the
>   object into the modified class.

That's untrue for a start. You need to have a good look at the Versioning section of the Object Serialization specification before you go any further.